# How to use domain name from third party provider in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've read the guide provided by AWS for [adding a custom domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstarts/latest/webapp/expanding-environments.html?icmpid=docs_eb_console_new#expanding-environments-domain).

For beginners like me in this platform, reading it just brings more confusion.
If it's possible, it would be really great if someone can create a step by step walkthrough on how to get this done.

So the scenario is, I have a domain which I purchased from a third-party provider and not from Route53. Now, I want to use this domain to point to one our loadbalancing-enabled elastic beanstalk application. This ELB app isn't also using VPC and I can't even modify my Network settings.

[image]

I want to point the domain using A record and not a sub-domain(CNAME) to this ELB app.

**Edit:**

For additional information, my domain name provider is [GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer might change depending on who is managing your DNS records. Check if they support A-ALIAS records for the zone apex. If they do the steps will be similar to the document link below.

Move your DNS servers to Route 53. How? that depends on who is your current DNS provider.

Next, create an A-ALIAS record in Route 53 pointing to your Elastic Beanstalk DNS name. Complete this step for the zone apex (domain.com) and www (www.domain.com).

[Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment's Domain Name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate where can I get my Elastic Beanstalk DNS name? thanks

Comment: In the document link that I included in my answer. The first paragraph has a screenshot. In summary, go to your EB environment dashboard: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-console.html#environments-dashboard

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comment isn't really helping, I already went to the documentation over and over before but I really couldn't get my mind on it. It always mentioning subdomains, but what I want is not a subdomain. That's why I'm asking if someone could create a dumb-proof walkthrough

Comment: The domain name that EB provides you is a subdomain. You map that to the domain name in Route 53. AWS provides very clear steps. There are no other steps that would be simpler. Sorry that I cannot help further.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your time.